# what is the loop invariant of this piece of code?

Tags: algorithm, loop-invariant

```
  int y = 0;
  while(y<x){
    y = y+1;
  }
```

I wanted to prove that y is equal to x if x is > 0, otherwise it equals to 0. What's the loop invariant that allows me to prove that? For the case where x > 0, I came up with the invariant `i <= x and y = i` where `i` is an extra variable that I introduced to represent the current loop iteration. Is there a way to write the invariant w/o introducing the extra variable?

Comment: The invariant is simply `y <= x or x < 0`.

Comment: @kaya3 is your invariant strong enough to prove that y = 0 if x < 0? Doesn't seem like the case but maybe I am missing something